# Does irish moss affect the amount of yeast left at bottling?

Tags: carbonation, irish-moss

I made a brown ale kit and used irish moss  in it for the first time. After putting it in I realized that I had misunderstood my LHBS and added 1 tablespoon instead of one teaspoon. I left in primary and secondary each for a week to get the eggdrop soup in the fermentors to settle out. 
 
 Three weeks later in bottles at 70F they still have very little carbonation. I have tried rolling them every three days for the last two weeks and still no change. 
 
 Could the amount of irish moss have caused some of the yeast to get trapped in what fell to the bottom? And the time honored question, after three weeks at those temps and rolling the bottles, is this all the carbonation I could expect to see?

Comment: Are you sure you primed the beer with sugar before bottling?  Its often an easy thing to overlook sometimes.

Comment: Positive. It has carbonation, just very little. It bubbles up when I pour and gets a thin layer of head, then it all disappears after two-three sips.

Comment: How warm can I get the bottles to see if that would help, they have been at about 68-70 but would going even warmer help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Irish moss works on the proteins in the beer. It has a negative charge, which binds the proteins which are positively charged.  Although some yeast *might* have gotten trapped as the proteins fell out it wouldn't be enough to keep the beer from carbing.  It will have no direct affect on the yeast.

Comment: Any other thought as to why there is no carb? The irish moss is the only thing that I did differently than my previous batches that ended up fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the kit was a brown ale *EXTRACT KIT* then one has to wonder why Irish moss was used at all. Irish moss is normally used to clear protein coagulate from all grain mashes/worts.